# Flutter project issue with enabling Android/iOS

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'd like to be able to add Android/iOS build at a later time. There seem to be an issue on adding Android/iOS support after the project has been created.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a new Flutter Project
2. Only have web enabled

[image: new Flutter project]

3. Add Android config with `flutter config --enable-android`
4. I've tried restarting Android Studio. Running `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and `flutter pub upgrade` has no effect.

Any idea on what might've gone wrong? I've also tried searching around and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get this working. The only workaround I can think of at present is to just create a new Flutter project and migrate the existing code from lib/

I'm currently using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK 
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.0.1, Build version 12A7300
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `flutter config --enable-android/ios` doesn't add the missing Android/iOS files in the project. `flutter create --platforms=android,ios [PROJECT]` should be run instead.